# How to get the count of a substing in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, count, substring, oracle-sqldeveloper, distinct

I have a table with phone numbers in a column. I want to return the amount of times a certain area code appears using `COUNT(*)`.

```
PHONE:
555-555-5565
323-595-8686
666-565-5232
323-599-0000
```

After Query:

```
ZIP:   FREQUENCY:
555    1
323    2
666    1
```

Non-working Query:

```
select distinct (substr(phone,0,3)) as "AREA_CODE", count(distinct substr(phone,0,3)) as "COUNT",
from address
```

I feel like I should be getting the substring of the phone number that is the area code as one result column, and then counting the frequency with the other, but I can’t seem to get it to work. Help?

Comment: Why are you referring to phone numbers as "zip code?"

Comment: YOu mean area code. Instead of using distinct use `group by substr(phone,0,3)` then just count(*)

Comment: @OldProgrammer because it's been a long day. FTFY. Any suggestions on how to fix the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does the idea of using `select distinct` for this type of query come from?

The proper construct is `group by`.  Learn SQL!

```
select substr(phone, 1, 3)) as "AREA_CODE", count(*) as "COUNT"
from address
group by substr(phone, 1, 3)) as "AREA_CODE";
```

Notes:

- `substr()` starts counts from "1" not "0".
- `count(distinct)` is not appropriate.  It would only return 1 when referring to the `group by` key.
- In fact, `distinct` is very special purpose in SQL.  You generally want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an temp table which store your zip :

```
create table #TempTable 
(
    Zip Varchar(3)   
)
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Zip ) 
SELECT substr(phone,0,3) from Address
```

Then you can query and count this result:

```
Select Zip , count(distinct Zip ) as FREQUENCY
from #TempTable
group by Zip
```